# Problema con Input::Old select laravel

Tags: html5, laravel-5, laravel

Estoy realizando un registro, y tengo un problema que al validar los selects, si ocurre un error y vuelve a la pagina de registro no me queda el valor cuando utilizo un ng-repeat.

Este caso donde tengo 2 option dentro del select si funciona:

```
 <select name="sexo" id="sexo" class="form-control">
      <option value="" hidden>-- Seleccionar --</option>
      <option value="Hombre" 
         @if (Input::old('sexo') == 'Hombre') selected="selected" @endif>Hombre</option>
      <option value="Mujer"
         @if (Input::old('sexo') == 'Mujer') selected="selected" @endif>Mujer</option>
  </select>
```

Pero cuando tengo muchos valores no me funciona como en este caso, que es para seleccionar el día de cumpleaños:

```
 <select name="dia" id="dia" class="form-control">   
     <option value="" hidden="">Día</option>
     <option ng-repeat="dia in listaDias" 
       value="<%dia.dia%>" 
       {{ (Input::old('dia') == '<%dia.dia%>' ? "selected" : "") }} ><%dia.dia%></option>
 </select>
```

Si le saco las comillas simple a `'<%dia.dia%>'`, me tira error.
Si le pongo `Input::old('dia') == 3` (por decir algun numero, deja marcado el último número que seria el 31).

Si no hay una solución con el `ng-repeat`, acepto otras formas de cargar los 31 números de ese select.

Comment: ng-repeat tiene que ver con Angular, ¿no?

Comment: Asi es, pero si hay otra forma de hacerlo seria bueno tmb

Answer (score 2):

Lo pude solucionar haciendo lo siguiente en la vista del html:

```
  @for($i=1; $i<=31;$i++)
    <option  value="{{$i}}"
      {{ (Input::old('dia') == $i ? "selected" : "") }}>{{$i}}</option>
  @endfor
```